# Assign double to matrix struct does only work for a single value but iterating over that number creates an error in C?

Tags: c, matrix, memory

I am trying to asssign values to an allocated matrix datastructure in C.
First the data is allocated for an n x m matrix (type double and all initialized to 0).
Than I iterate over that matrix and try to assign a value. For example:

```
void TestMatrix( Matrix M )
{

    double n = 1;

    for (size_t i =0; i < M.R; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < M.C; j++)
        {
            M.Data[ i ][ j ] = n;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this causes a crash while removing the iteration over n:

```
{
M.Data[ i ][ j];
//n++;
}
```

Does work.
In other words I can create a m x n matrix filled with 1's but not with 1, 2, 3 ... etc. I want to do the latter.

I am just learning C so it might be something obvious. Can anyone help me?

For extra information the datastructure is:

```
typedef struct { int R, C;
double **Data;
} Matrix;
```

And the memory is allocated as:

```
Matrix AllocateMatrix( int R, int C )
{
Matrix M;
int i;
M.Data = NULL;
M.R = M.C = 0;
if( ( R <= 0 ) || ( C <= 0 ) ) return( M );
M.R = R;
M.C = C;
M.Data = calloc( R, sizeof( double * ) );
for( i = 0; i < R; ++i )
M.Data[ i ] = calloc( C, sizeof( double ) );
return( M );
}
```

Edit 1 (I noticed when I commented out another function the problem did not appear anymore. I try to do Gauss Jordan elimination on the matrix. It might be the case that that part of the code just does not cause the error when I feed it a matrix filled with a single variable.) As requested the code that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct { int R, C;
double **Data;
} Matrix;

Matrix AllocateMatrix( int R, int C )
{
Matrix M;
int i;
M.Data = NULL;
M.R = M.C = 0;
if( ( R <= 0 ) || ( C <= 0 ) ) return( M );
M.R = R;
M.C = C;
M.Data = calloc( R, sizeof( double * ) );
for( i = 0; i < R; ++i )
M.Data[ i ] = calloc( C, sizeof( double ) );
return( M );
}

void IdentityMatrix( Matrix M )
{
    int i, j;
    if( M.Data == NULL ) return;

    for( i = 0; i < M.R; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < M.C; j++ )
        {
            if (i == j)
            M.Data[ i ][ j ] = 1;
            else
            M.Data[ i ][ j ] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void TestMatrix( Matrix M ) // Own function
{

    int n;
    n = 1;

    for (size_t i =0; i < M.R; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < M.C; j++)
        {
            M.Data[ i ][ j ] = n;
            n++;
        }
    }
}

void PrintMatrix( Matrix M )
{
int i, j;
if( M.Data == NULL ) return;
for( i = 0; i < M.R; i++ )
{
for( j = 0; j < M.C; j++ )
printf( "%20.12lE", M.Data[ i ][ j ] );
printf( "\n" );
}
printf( "\n" );
}

void FreeMatrix( Matrix M )
{
int i;
if( ( !M.R ) || ( !M.C ) || ( M.Data == NULL ) ) return;

for( i = 0; i < M.R; i++ )
{
    free( M.Data[ i ] );
}

free( M.Data );
}

void DoGaussJordan( Matrix A, Matrix B ) 
{
    /* do gauss jordan algorithm on matrix A using pivoting and apply
    all elementary row operations performed on A on B too. */

    if( ( A.Data == NULL ) || ( B.Data == NULL ) ) return;
    if( A.R != B.R ) return;

    /* Start algoritm */

    int i = 0,j = 0,k = 0;
    double temp;
    double range_zero = pow(10, -15);

    for( i=0; i<A.R; i++ )
    {

        for( k=i+1; k<A.R; k++ )
        {
            //If diagonal element(absolute value) is smaller than any of the terms below it
            if( fabs(A.Data[i][i]) < fabs(A.Data[k][i]) )
            {
                //Swap the rows
                for( j=0; j<A.C; j++ )
                {          
                    temp=A.Data[i][j];
                    A.Data[i][j]=A.Data[k][j];
                    A.Data[k][j]=temp;

                    // mirror with  matrix B
                    temp=B.Data[i][j];
                    B.Data[i][j]=B.Data[k][j];
                    B.Data[k][j]=temp;                    
                }
            }
        }

    if( -1*range_zero < fabs(A.Data[i][i]) && range_zero > fabs(A.Data[i][i])) // 0 in pivot means zero determinant so the inverse does not exist
        {
            printf("ZERO DETERMINANT\n");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < B.R; i++)
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < B.C; j++)
                {
                    B.Data[i][j] = 0;
                } 
            }
            return;
        }
        
    // Begin Gauss Elimination

    /* Reduce all cells below pivot to 0 and do the same operation on the corresponding rows right to the pivot */
    for( k=i+1; k<A.R; k++ )
    {
        temp = A.Data[k][i]/ A.Data[i][i];
        for( j=0 ;j<A.C ;j++ )
        {
            B.Data[k][j]= B.Data[k][j] - temp *B.Data[i][j]; // Mirror B

            A.Data[k][j]= A.Data[k][j] - temp *A.Data[i][j]; // Transform A
        }
    }

    /* Normalize pivot i.e. divide row i by pivot cell */
    for( int j = 0; j < B.C; j++ )
    {
        B.Data[i][j] /= A.Data[i][i]; // First mirror operation on whole row B
    }

    for( int j = A.C; j >= i; j-- )
    {
        A.Data[i][j] /= A.Data[i][i]; // Than transform matrix A  
    }

    /* Do backward substitution */
    for( k=0;k < i;k++ )
    {
        for( j = i + 1; j < A.C; j++ )
        {
        A.Data[k][j] = A.Data[k][j] - A.Data[i][j] * A.Data[k][i]; // transform all values in row k to the right of pivot column i
        }


        for( j = 0; j < A.C; j++ )
        // Doing the same operation (multiply and subtract) accross all columns of B
        {
        B.Data[k][j] = B.Data[k][j] - B.Data[i][j] * A.Data[k][i];
        }
        // Effectively x[k][i] = x[k][i] - 1x[k][i] = 0 
        A.Data[k][i] = 0;
    }
    }       
}

int main()
{
int r = 0; 
int c = 0; 
int size = 0;

r = c = 3; // Specify size of square matrix

/* Allocate matrices */
Matrix my_Matrix = AllocateMatrix(r, c);
Matrix inverse_My_Matrix = AllocateMatrix(r, c);

/* Fill matrices with values */
TestMatrix( my_Matrix ); // This generates a zero determinant matrix.
IdentityMatrix( inverse_My_Matrix ); 

printf("\n-- Input matrix --\n");
PrintMatrix( my_Matrix );

/* Convert my_matrix into identity matrix and shadow same operations
on another identity matrix which gives the inverse matrix*/
DoGaussJordan( my_Matrix, inverse_My_Matrix);

printf("\n-- After Gaus Jordan --");
printf("\nInput matrix to reduced echlon:\n");
PrintMatrix( my_Matrix );

printf("\nInverted matrix:\n");
PrintMatrix( inverse_My_Matrix );

/* Free allocated memory */
FreeMatrix( my_Matrix );
FreeMatrix( inverse_My_Matrix );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: in all of your code it seems you insist on copying everything, having a function argument `Matrix M` will copy the M and you end up with two Matrix with pointers that point to the same memory location, this could screw up things. Instead allocate M once with calloc/malloc and pass the pointer around

Comment: Your code works for me, I assume there is an error somewhere else. -- Even as you have a copy of `M` given to `TestMatrix`, this is a shallow copy, as such the pointer to `Data` is also a copy, and so the function fills the array of the original matrix. -- OT: Why don't you allocate a real 2D array?

Comment: Adding to comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684377/assign-double-to-matrix-struct-does-only-work-for-a-single-value-but-iterating-o#comment128388916_72684377: I assume `TestMatrix` is supposed to fill the `Matrix` you pass as an argument. In your implementation this works only because the copy of the `Matrix`, that is created when calling the function, contains a pointer pointing to the same memory as the original `Matrix` in the caller. The result may be what you want, but the way it works might not be obvious. Use a pointer when you want to modify an argument inside a function.

Comment: What Vlad is referring to is [mre].

Comment: @SupportUkraine My bad, the function returns it by value.

Comment: @SupportUkraine the if statement above that checks if A.Data[i][i] is close to 0 and stops the program if it is.

Comment: @SupportUkraine it is the out of bound yes! Wow I completly missed that one. Thank you so much!